# Use Youtube API without authentication

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api, pagekit

I'm trying to make a widget for CMS Sites where I can authenticate my user on the admin page and then show a timer to the next youtube live broadcast and link directly to it from my page.

I have successfully used the `youtube.liveBroadcasts.list` api and received a list of my broadcasts and showing it on a page. But I want to be able to show this(about my channel) on a page when another user visits the page, without the need to login or use authentication of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

I think to use this requests from Youtube API, a Login is Required. For example when you just paste this in your browser
[LiveBroadcasts.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list#try-it) URI request in your browser

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts
```

without being logged-on you'd get an error:

```
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"message": "Login Required",
"locationType": "header",
"location": "Authorization",
```

I think it would also help to read on [Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication).

These are the supported OAuth flows:

> 1. The server-side flow supports web applications that can securely store persistent information.
> 2. The client-side flow supports JavaScript applications running in a browser.
> 3. The installed application flow supports applications installed on a device, such as a phone or computer.
> 4. The device flow supports devices with limited input capabilities, such as game consoles and video cameras.
>
> *The service account flow supports server-to-server interactions that do not access user information. However, the YouTube Data API does not
>   support this flow. Since there is no way to link a Service Account to
>   a YouTube account, attempts to authorize requests with this flow will
>   generate a NoLinkedYouTubeAccount error.

In short, I think you need to be authorized to perform this API call.